# List search in Prolog

Tags: list, search, recursion, prolog

I'm trying to make a search in a list in Prolog, but I would like to start right at a certain position. Will I have to do that boring recursive search?

Thank you.

Comment: Lists are sequential in Prolog. Unless you have a reference to a mid-list position, you can't access it except by sequential beheading (AKA "that boring recursive search").

Answer (score 0):

you can Skip N positions using N free_vars, and append/3 to get rid of list' header:

```
?- [user].
|: find(Needle, Haystack, Skip) :-
|:       length(Header, Skip),
|:       append(Header, Actual, Haystack),
|:       memberchk(Needle, Actual).
|: % user://1 compiled 0,04 sec, 2 clauses
true.

?- find(3-X,[1-alfa,2-beta,3-gamma,4-delta,1-abba,2-bridge],1).
X = gamma.

?- find(3-X,[1-alfa,2-beta,3-gamma,4-delta,1-abba,2-bridge],3).
false.

?- find(3-X,[1-alfa,2-beta,3-gamma,4-delta,1-abba,2-bridge],2).
X = gamma.
```

If there are many search to to, the list build `length(Header, Skip)` it's better done once...